# SharePoint GetListItemChangesSinceToken does not return items recursively

Tags: .net, soap, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have to repair a .NET 4.5 application that communicates with a SharePoint site.

This application uses the function GetListItemChangesSinceToken to retrieve new items from a SharePoint library.

But, since recently, for an unknown reason, this function returns only the content which is at the root of this library and do not parse recursively the sub content anymore.

Yet, neither the code of the application, neither the structure of the library (on client side) has been changed. (I have no vision on what is done on server side).

I have tried to replace the GetListItemChangesSinceToken with the function GetListItems (to eliminate some possible causes of the problem) and the result is the same.

My question is : Is there a way to force the GetListItemChangesSinceToken function to parse recursively the subcontent of its target library?

I have read that it is supposed to be its default behavior so I am puzzled by this.

If it is not possible, is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found a way to retrieve items that are at the root of a subfolders by using " Full url of the subfolder " in the queryOptions parameter.

This is the only "solution" I have found so far.